# Disable automatic population of models in sails v1.0

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using Sailsjs `v1.0.0-36`. I want to disable model population.

So when I send GET request to `http://my-app/pets`:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    breed: 'Wolves',
    type: 'Direwolf',
    name: 'Ghost',
    owner: 1, //user id
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    breed: 'Wolves',
    type: 'Direwolf',
    name: 'Summer',
    owner: 1, //user id
  },
]
```

and when I send GET request to `http://my-app/users`:

```
[
  {
     id: 1
     firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Snow',
     pets: [ //array of pets id
       1,
       2,
     ]
  }
]
```

Where `User` model defined as

```js
// myApp/api/models/User.js
// A user may have many pets
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    // Add a reference to Pets
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
};
```

And `Pet` model defined as

```js
// myApp/api/models/Pet.js
// A pet may only belong to a single user
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    breed: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    // Add a reference to User
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

In Sails `v0.12.0` you can do that in `/config/blueprints.js` by setting

```
populate = false
```

But this is deprecated in Sails `v1.0`, following [this](https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints) from the docs we can achieve that by overriding `parseBlueprintOptions`, and [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/parse-blueprint-options.js) is the default implementation of the function.

How can I override this to achieve the required results?

Answer (score 1):

Saw one implementation here:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4130#issuecomment-310720365

```
parseBlueprintOptions(req) {
    var queryOptions = req._sails.hooks.blueprints.parseBlueprintOptions(req);

    if(!req.param('populate', false) && !queryOptions.alias) {
      queryOptions.populates = {};
    }
    return queryOptions;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [commit](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/d8f4df8e19cfb7eaefa00bbcbbc6cab870483194) sailjs 1.0 started to support this option again.